# How to check for a record in one table and insert in another table?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

```
create procedure checkin_customerid(in customer_id int) 
    if (select c.customerID from customer_detail c
    where customer_id = c.customerID)
    then 
    insert into customer_checkin (customerID)
    values (customer_id);
```

I am trying to create this procedure in MySQL that should:

- check if there is a match for the customerID in the table customer_details and
- if true, should add the customer_id in the table customer_checkin.

But I am getting an error on the last line: values (customer_id); which says:

*Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4*

Hovering over code error says: Statement incomplete, expecting a ';'
The bracket on the last line for `(customer_id)` is underlined.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of the select

Comment: ```BEGIN``` and no ```END;``` maybe.

Comment: ```INSERT INTO customer_checkin (customerID) SELECT customer_id FROM customer_detail WHERE c.customerID = customer_id LIMIT 1;``` will do the job in shorter way

Comment: @OlivierDepriester sorry the begin shouldn't be there

Comment: @OlivierDepriester It worked!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You have a missing END IF;

And i would rewrite the if clause to [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkin_customerid(in customer_id int) 
BEGIN
    if (EXISTS(select c.customerID from customer_detail c
        where customer_id = c.customerID))
    then 
        insert into customer_checkin (customerID)
        values (customer_id); 
    END IF;
 END
```

But Oiliver is right only for the insert the if clause is not necessary

Comment: I got errors on the ```end if``` and ```end``` when I tried to use begin-end. Is it because I am using MySQL Workbench?

Comment: And yes, I went with Olivier's recommendation. Thank you for the answer though, @nbk!

Comment: So I tried it out again and it is working now, but I had to change the delimiters in my code.